# Как переместить вложенный div вправо?

Tags: html, css

Как переместить вложенный div class="span3 reason_for_leaving"  вправо?

```
<div id='reason_for_leaving' class="row-fluid">
        <!--dropdown menu-->
        <div class="span3 reason_for_leaving">
            <h5>Reason For Leaving</h5>
            <div class="controls">

                <select name="reason_for_leaving"  class="span12" data-placeholder="- Select One -" autocomplete="off">

                    <option><a href="#">A</a></option>
                    <option><a href="#">B</a></option>
                    <option><a href="#">C</a></option>
                    <option><a href="#">D</a></option>
                    <option selected><a href="#">No Reason Given</a></option>


                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

добавте классу .row-fluid следующие свойства
(width задаете необходимый вам)

```
.row-fluid {
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}
```

Comment: Я использую display:none для того чтобы в  jquery показывать\скрывать элемент,т.к. с visibility:hidden работает не корректно. Но спасибо за ответ.Не знал про  flex,блок и правда стал вправо,только не подходит по моему коду. Но ответ защитан как рабочий:)

Answer (score 0):

свойство float:right; У дива родителя должна быть задана ширина

Comment: Задал такие параметры,но не помогло.Внутренний див остался слева:                                          
  #reason_for_leaving{

    display:none;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.reason_for_leaving{
    float:right;
}

Comment: Если у родителя стоит display:none; вы ничего не увидите. Это похоже на выпадающую менюшку, и скорее всего насколько я понимаю вам надо что б она не с левой стороны а с правой выезжала. А это надо лезть в свойства анимации. Вообще нужен код

Comment: display:none стоит по умолчанию,чтобы при выборе определенного значения в другом селекте появлялся этот див со своим select. А мне нужно чтобы див class="span3 reason_for_leaving находился справа, без анимации

Comment: Получилось,но выглядит ужасно:( #reason_for_leaving{

    display:none;
    padding-left: 910px;
}